# Why dooes my bootstrap button group look funny

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to get a button group working like the ones on the bootstrap page.

## HTML

```
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-class="{active: active_views[0]}" ng-click="changeView(0)">R-Theta</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-class="{active: active_views[1]}" ng-click="changeView(1)">Cartesian</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-class="{active: active_views[2]}" ng-click="changeView(2)">Longitudinal</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-class="{active: active_views[3]}" ng-click="">Console</button </div>
        </div>
```

### Result

[image]

### Expected

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're using Bootstrap V4?

Comment: Not sure, shouldnt this work with V3 though?

Comment: Btn-secondary is specifically for V4. You need btn-default for V3.